# python cannot open and edit a .reg file

Tags: python

I am trying to edit a .reg file in python to replace strings in a file. I can do this for any other file type such as .txt.

Here is the python code:

```
with open ("C:/Users/UKa51070/Desktop/regFile.reg", "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()
print data
```

It returns an empty string

Comment: you probably need to read that file in binary mode. try: `open ("C:/Users/UKa51070/Desktop/regFile.reg", "rb")` (note the `b`).

Comment: I already tried that - doesn't work

Comment: What is the content of the file?

Comment: a windows registry file - at the top of the file it says: 'Windows Registry Editor version 5.00'   The rest of the file is just text

Comment: Isn't it easier and better to do registery modification via python directly?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are not seeing any output, perhaps you could try:

`print len(data)`

Depending on your version of Windows, your `REG` file will be saved using UTF-16 encoding, unless you specifically export it using the `Win9x/NT4` format.

You could try using the following script:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open("C:/Users/UKa51070/Desktop/regFile.reg", encoding='utf-16') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()
print data
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a good idea to edit `.reg` files manually. My suggestion is to search for a Python package that handles it for you. I think the  [_winreg](https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html) Python built-in library is what you are looking for.